# Rails has_many relation returning wrong number of model objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Rails version: 3.1.10

Hi. I have a `user` model with a `has_many` relationship to an `account` model. For one particular user, there are 5 accounts. However, when I ask for the related models, I only get 3 back:

```
> user.accounts.class
 => Array
> user.accounts.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = 1
 => 5
> user.accounts.all.class
 => Array
> user.accounts.all.count
 => 3
```

I figure there's some ActiveRecord caching going on because the call to `user.accounts.all` doesn't generate a database query. But the thing that really stumps me is even though `user.accounts.class` and `user.accounts.all.class` are both equal to `Array`, calling the `:count` method does two entirely different things.

I'm fairly new to ruby, but I know you can do some magic with defining methods on objects on the fly. Is that what's happening here? Is ActiveRecord giving me a modified `Array` in the first case?

Comment: Is there a accounts_count column on User? Does Answer have a belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true?

Comment: Not exactly, no. But I realized we're using the `record-cache` gem, and there's a `cache_records key: "account", index: [ :user_id ], store: :shared` in the `Account` model. Commenting that out made all the difference.

Comment: There you go :) It has always been related to caching, each time I had a similar issue

Comment: I think its not related to caching. You're using `Users.accounts.all.count`. That will call the **count** method of the **Array** Class whereas `Users.accounts.all` calls the **count** method of **ActiveRecord** class. In activerecord method chaining the order of the methods matter sometimes.

Comment: In the above comment I meant **whereas** `Users.accounts.count` **calls the count method of Active..**. Also above two methods should return the value **5**. So there may be some problem in active record. but you can try posting the query and result of the `Users.accounts.all` here for more help.